# jboss as 7 hosting provider

Tags: jboss, hosting, jboss7.x

I have created a JAVA EE6 Application and i would like to host it on the J BOSS as 7 Platform. Can someone point me to a good and reliable web hosting provider.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Checkout [OpenShift](https://openshift.redhat.com). There is a free version and now an enterprise version too.

It's also available on [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2008/06/17/jboss-on-amazon-ec2/).